# Can't install Ubuntu 19.10 shows black screen GTX 750 Ti with dell precision e5-1620 with no intel hd graphics built-in

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

Hi Everyone I have a workstation from dell Precision T3600 with intel Xeon E5-1620 CPU with no intel hd graphics on it..I am using gtx 750 Ti graphics card with it.
When I try to install Ubuntu it shows grub boot menu and then after selecting try or install option then monitor shows "Signal out of range" and it boots up but doesn't show any display and after a while the monitor goes to sleep...
I am using VGA interface and HP EliteDisplay E231 1080p.
Please help I am fed up with windows 10

Comment: You typically need nomodeset until you install the nVidia driver from Ubuntu repository. See section on editing grub. You can replace quiet splash with nomodeset in grub menu's Linux line. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: sir I also tried this but nothing happend

Comment: Did you replace quiet splash? As then you should see line by line the boot process. If boot crashes, it often is not last line posted, but several lines above.

Comment: Sir I edited the linux Line at the end with nomodeset=0

Comment: Thanks sir It worked now I just replaced the quiet splash only and it worked previously I was expanding the line...thanks sir it really worked.m

Comment: Glad it worked.

Comment: but Sir now I am having another issue that I can't boot into the system.I tried to install easyBCD to create entry point but even then it showed in boot menu but still doesn't boot....And now I can't edit the menu

Comment: Do you also have Windows? EasyBCD is for Windows and only with the older BIOS/MBR configuration. Can you from grub menu boot recovery mode, second line in grub? If you do not get grub menu, you may need Escape if UEFI or shift if BIOS right after BIOS/UEFI screen.